# Replace using a dictionary and an anonymous function

Tags: python, replace, anonymous-function

I'm working with some replaces in python and I noticed and I can work through dictionaries. Is there any way to make the function I'm using anonymous? I thought like this, but I can't understand the error.

Thanks in advance!

Working:

```
itens = ['bad cat', 'good fish'] 

d = {
    'cat': 'dog',
    'fish': 'turtle'
}

def f(s):
  for i,j in d.items():
    s = s.replace(i,j)
  return s

itens_trans = [f(item) for item in itens]
print(itens_trans)
```

Not working:

```
itens_trans = [lambda item: for i,j in d.items(): item.replace(i,j) for item in itens]
print(itens_trans)
```

Comment: What is your error? please post it

Comment: Why are you using a list-comprehension?

Comment: Also, a dict really doesn't make sense here, you are merely using it to iterate over it's pairs, if that's all you are using it, just use a list of tuples or lists of lists

Comment: You cannot put stuff like a `for` loop or an `if` statement within the lambda in a list like that.

Comment: You can't use a for-loop in an lambda expression, they are *purposefully limited to only expressions, not statements*.  To achieve what you are doing using purely lambda expressions you'd need a complicated, recursive lambda with the fixed-point operator... which is a theoretically interesting thing but not something you'd *ever really use*. In this case, though, you can probably just use `functools.reduce`

Comment: You can't do what you want with a one-liner list comprehension, in large part because the changes to `s` are cumulative.

Comment: I seem to have found a way using reduce()

Answer (score 0):

This clears it up my earlier attempt. Though readability is rough.

```
$ python 
Python 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information. 
>>> itens = ['bad cat', 'good fish'] 
>>> d = {'cat': 'dog', 'fish': 'turtle'}
>>> import re
>>> [s.replace(i, j) for i, j in d.items() for s in itens if i in s]
['bad dog', 'good turtle']
>>> [f(item) for item in itens]
['bad dog', 'good turtle']
```

UPDATE: per juanpa-arrivillaga, need to work with "good cat and fish".

```
>>> itens
['bad cat', 'good fish', 'good cat and fish']
>>> [reduce(lambda s, sub: s.replace(*sub), [target, *tuple(d.items())]) for target in itens]
['bad dog', 'good turtle', 'good dog and turtle']

# maybe more readable
>>> [reduce(lambda s, sub: s.replace(*sub),
...         [target, *tuple(d.items())])
...  for target in itens]
['bad dog', 'good turtle', 'good dog and turtle']
```

Comment: `str.replace` *does not work in-place*. No string methods work in-place, i.e. `str` objects are immutable in Python...\

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga. Yep, was not thinking it through. fixed above.

Comment: Sure, but this still isn't equivalent. The OP gave a bad example, but try it with `"good cat and fish"`